# Mininet tcp src port

Tags: mininet, openflow

I am doing an exercise on mininet(novice here), i want to block traffic originating from a particular src port. How can that be accessed as in some option similar to "dl_dst"?

Regards,
Babar Rehman

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Openflow message to handle your case. So, you will need to create a FlowMod message with a Match based on the port you want to block. Since you want to block flows, your action will be void.

Answer (score 0):

To block the traffic based on the source port, you can add a flow using ovs-ofctl command. Let's say, the TCP source port to be locked is 80, then the following command can be used on mininet prompt (mininet>) to block source port 80:
sh ovs-ofctl add s1 dl_type=0x800,nw_proto=6,tp_src=80,actions=drop

In the above command, s1 is the name of the bridge.

Please refer to OVS commands for adding flows in the document at http://www.pica8.com/document/v2.3/pdf/ovs-commands-reference.pdf